# Как в Docker контейнере посмотреть ip адрес компьютера

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Собственно весь вопрос в названии. Я хотел бы генерировать ссл сертификаты и иметь ip адрес компьютера, но при запросе получается адрес контейнера что мне не нужно, вопрос, что делать?
Хотелось бы полностью автоматизировать весь процесс развертки и генерации сертификатов, без лишних скриптов если конечно это возможно.
Ip адрес получаю через команду `hostname -I`

Comment: вы имеете ввиду адрес хоста на котором запушен `Docker`? если да, то какой публичный по которому к вам подключаются?

Comment: Да, хост на котором развернут докер, я его знаю и знаю как его добыть, но не знаю как этот процесс автоматизировать и сделать так чтоб это всё происходило без моего ведома. В плане считывание этого адреса и генерация внутри докера

Comment: если вы знаете как его получить, то его можно передавать как env vars в контрейнер, а внутри их проверять

Comment: Из вопроса в названии понятно ровно ничего. 
Ваш компьютер имеет как минимум несколько ip адресов. Это адрес смотрящий в интернет, localhost, интерфейс docker0 и еще несколько которые появляются при запуске контейнеров.

Comment: @zalex, не просто «несколько», а несколько миллионов. причём даже если компьютер вообще ни к чему не подключен. это я про `127.0.0.0/8`

Answer (score 0):

Ответ придуманный мной пока это взять этот IP и просто использовать его как переменную контейнера.